# PHP stream_socket_client ignoring timeout

Tags: php, sockets, zend-framework2, zend-mail, stream-socket-client

I'm using `zend_mail` from `zend-framework2` in my project to send some amount of emails in a loop, but sometimes it takes more than usual to send an email.
After doing some research, i found that the delay occurs on the `stream_socket_client` function.
I tried to set this function's timeout to acceptable value, but it seems to ignore that setting.
Also tried to use `STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT` to limit the number of opened sockets but with no luck.

Average `stream_socket_client` times are about 0.03 seconds and occasionally it takes from 5 seconds up to even 40 seconds. Every value above 0.5 seconds is unacceptable for me. I'm out of ideas what can cause that issue.

Current setup:

```
$start = microtime(true);  

$this->socket = @stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT);

echo 'Stream socket: '.(microtime(true) -  $start);
```

Comment: What errors do you get, when you remove the `@` suppressor?

Comment: No errors at all. That's the problem.

Comment: `self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION` Have you tried changing that value in `php.ini default_socket_timeout` too?

Comment: Still no luck.. `ini_get("default_socket_timeout"): 0.05`
`Stream socket: 5.0396149158478`

Comment: Then are you really sure that the problem is not somewhere else? I suggest you debug line by line or check if the timeout does not get overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i don't know where to look anymore. I've even put `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 0.05)` right before `stream_socket_client`. `self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION` also equals 0.05 right before socket opening..

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem meanwhile?